# QT VsAddIn error Object reference not set to an instanse of an object

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

My Qt version - 5.12.3
VS version - 2017

Builded Qt from sources as follows:

```
SET _ROOT = D:\Qt\src
SET PATH = %_ROOT%\qtbase\bin;%_ROOT%\gnuwin32\bin;%PATH%
configure -static -static-runtime -release -platform win32-msvc - opensource -confirm-license -nomake examples -nomake tests -prefix 
D:\Qt\build
jom
jom install
```

Building was successfull. No errors occured.

Installed QtVsAddIn, added previously built qt to extention.

When creationg any qt project i see this error:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tried install AddIns for 19 and 15 version of VS, doesn't worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it was a bug in QT VSAddin. Moved to QTCreator.